# Applying symbology based on existing STYLE File based on value on attribute field

Tags: arcpy, symbology

I wanted to automate the application of symbology from an existing style sheet based on a column (single Unique Value) in the attribute table of a shapefile.

Is this possible and if so what function would I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is NO.

If you read the ArcMap help file and look at the function [ListStyleItems()](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/liststyleitems.htm) it states that only legend items are supported. I doubt there is any automation in ArcGIS Pro as ArcMap styles require an import step to make them compatible as discussed [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/projects/styles.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_2D13B0FBB19D49BC9296F958A0EC77D9).

A possible manual solution is to create layerfiles using the symbology in your style file then script those in python using the apply symbology tool. Plenty of examples of code in this site and the Esri forum for that.